# Way to cache bust service worker remotely?

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker, workbox

After did some research about cache busting with service worker, the methods are always involved with push to live with new build with new cache name.

This means I need to push new code to live every time when I update some data on the backend.

Second choice is that use network only which will not be getting performance boost from cache.

I would like to know if there is anyway to update service worker remotely like push to all user and update cache or remove all cache

Comment: Just to clarify—what does "push to all user" mean here, given that you don't want to update your "live" web server? Are you saying that you want to use push notifications but you don't want to deploy anything new to your web server?

Comment: I just want to reset all users cache by some push event. So that they can get update right away. Is it more clear ?